# Run a intotify sricpt in background

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, inotify

how can i run 12 bash scripts simultaniously in the backgroud?

That's the script:

```
#/bin/bash

while inotifywait -e close_write /var/www/html/wp-content/QM-Handbuch /01-Inhaltsverzeichnis.doc;

    do       soffice --headless --convert-to pdf /var/www/html/wp-content/QM-Handbuch/01-Inhaltsverzeichnis.doc &&
             sudo mv /var/www/html/wp-content/QM-Handbuch/01-Inhaltsverzeichnis.pdf /var/www/html/wp-content
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the ampersand(&) you can run the bash scripts in background.

Syntax:-

```
   <prompt> $ bash <file name> &
```

Example:-

```
   <prompt> $ bash inotify.sh &
```